# Yii2 несколько полей Datepicker на одной странице с одинаковыми name

Tags: yii2, datepicker

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. Существует страница резерва столов. На ней находиться 5 ближайших мероприятий и на каждом по 10 столов для резерва. На каждом столе есть модальное окно с формой для резерва. Поля такие: имя, номер, время и скрытые поля (id мероприятия и id стола).

Собственно, когда вставляю виджет:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'time')->widget(kartik\time\TimePicker::className(), [
                'name' => 'table1',
                'value' => '20:00 PM',
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'showMeridian' => false,
                    'showSeconds' => false,

                ],'options'=>[
                    'readonly' => true,
                ],
            ])?>
```

то получаю следующее:

1. Первый стол работает, все хорошо:

   [image: Рабочий вариант]
2. А вот следующие — нет:

   [image: Нерабочий вариант]

Понимаю, что ошибка из-за одинакого id:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но не могу понять, как прописать `id` для всех разный. Либо сделать событие не на `id`, а на `class`.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем много модалок? Если там все идентично. 1 модалка и в зависимости какая кнопка открыла, какая-то кастомизация формы. Тогда 1 модалка 1 id нет проблем и нет лишнего кода.
Но сменить id не проблема, например так:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'time')->widget(kartik\time\TimePicker::className(), ['id'=>'myUniqueId'
```